# Debuging a simple char driver in Linux failing on device_create()

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I wrote a simple char driver and would now like to register it automatically in udev using classes. My code consists of the `init` function called when the driver is loaded and `probe` function called when the driver is loading its devices (and of course their counter-equivalent `exit` and `remove`). The problem: Once a new device is added my `probe` function fails when executing the `device_create` command.
Now I am wondering why:

How can I possibly get more information about why this command fails (besides that it fails)? Any argument missing (like is there a problem with my global declaration of `fooClass`, should I move it to the `probe` function instead, which does not make sens in my eyes but is shown in many examples)? Or any other overseen error?

Following my code of which I stripped most return verification (like `IS_ERR()`) and clean up functions for readability. This two variables are defined globally:

```
static int foo_majNbr;
static struct class *fooClass;
```

`init` function:

```
static int __init foo_init(void)
{
    int rv;
    dev_t devNbr;

    /* Registering driver */
    rv = pci_register_driver(&foo_driver);
        /* ----> see answer below for correct order <---- */

    /* Create device class */
    fooClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);

    /* Allocate device number, just one device for the moment */
    rv = alloc_chrdev_region(&devNbr, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME);
    foo_majNbr = MAJOR(devNbr);

    ...
}
```

and the `probe` function:

```
static int __devinit foo_probe(struct pci_dev *dev,
    const struct pci_device_id *devId)
{
    struct foo_dev *foo_dev = 0;
    int rv = 0;

    /* Allocate memory in Kernel (for parameters) */
    foo_dev = kzalloc(sizeof(*foo_dev), GFP_KERNEL);
    foo_dev->pci_dev = dev;
    pci_set_drvdata(dev, foo_dev);

    foo_dev->devNbr = MKDEV(foo_majNbr, 1);

    /* Add class to device */
    foo_dev->dev = device_create(fooClass, NULL, foo_dev->devNbr,
        foo_dev, DEVICE_NAME);
    if (IS_ERR(foo_dev->dev)) {
        /* ----> INDICATES FAILURE HERE <---- */
    }

    /* Add char device */
    cdev_init(&foo_dev->cdev, &foo_fops);
    rv = cdev_add(&foo_dev->cdev, foo_dev->devNbr, 1);

    /* Enabling device */
    rv = pci_enable_device(dev);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should print the error number at least to know the reason.

```
pr_err("%s:%d error code %d\n", __func__, __LINE__, PTR_ERR(foo_dev->dev));
```

- PTR_ERR(): convert an invalid pointer to an error code
- ERR_PTR(): convert an error code to an invalid pointer
- IS_ERR(): check if a pointer is invalid and containing an error code
- IS_ERR_OR_NULL(): like above, plus it checks if the pointer is `NULL`

in the file [Linux/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h) you can find the most common errors. If this error code doesn't help you, you can go to the [source code of device_create()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/core.c#L1672) an find out where your kind of error is generated and understand why.

Maybe print also the arguments of `device_create()` before call it.

I know, this is not the kind of answer that magically solve you problem :) but it is a way to proceed and find out the reason.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for and it helped finding the problem :) - I posted the solution in a separated answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The question asks for information about debugging which is well explained in the previous answer. For the sake of completeness I would like to share the solution to the actual problem behind why `device_create()` failed:

Having a look at the `dmesg` log the following call history is presented after loading the module:

```
[ 2646.982482] [foo_init:246] CALL | Function called.
[ 2646.982499] [foo_probe:121] CALL | Function called.
[ 2646.982503] [foo_probe:147] ERR -19 | Failed to add device to class.
[ 2646.982535] [foo_init:279] OK | Driver loaded, Major number: 235.
```

As one can see, the `init()` function does not finish its routine before `probe()` is called. Therefore no class exists when `probe()` wants to add it to the device. The order of the commands called in `init()` is the problem: The driver registers itself already to the kernel before having finished its routine. `pci_register_driver()` has to be called only at the very end. Here the updated code:

```
static int __init foo_init(void)
{
    int rv;
    dev_t devNbr;

    /* Create device class */
    fooClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);

    /* Allocate device number, just one device for the moment */
    rv = alloc_chrdev_region(&devNbr, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME);
    foo_majNbr = MAJOR(devNbr);

    ...

    /* Registering driver */
    rv = pci_register_driver(&foo_driver);
        /* ----> has to be called at the very end! <---- */
}
```

The correct order counts also for the `exit()` function (as I found out after being confronted with another error leading to an Oops): First unregister the driver to unregister the device and only then destroy the class. The code is as following:

```
static void __exit foo_exit(void)
{
    pci_unregister_driver(&foo_driver);
    class_destroy(fooClass);
}
```